# Loading Assembly bytes in AppDomain

Tags: c#, .net, .net-assembly, appdomain

I'm trying to load an assembly into the appdomain.

> Failed to load assembly "Test.dll". System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Test, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

I'm using bytes to load the assembly, instead of paths.
I looked at an example which also specifies a Proxy class down below.

```
AppDomainSetup domaininfo = new AppDomainSetup();
domaininfo.ApplicationBase = System.Environment.CurrentDirectory;
Evidence adevidence = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Evidence;
dmname = AppDomain.CreateDomain("test", adevidence, domaininfo);
```

Loading:

```
Assembly = Store.dmname.Load(bytes);
```

Using the Proxy class:

```
        internal class Proxy : MarshalByRefObject
        {
            internal Assembly GetAssembly(byte[] assemblyPath)
            {
                try
                {
                    return Assembly.Load(assemblyPath);
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    return null;
                    // throw new InvalidOperationException(ex);
                }
            }
        }

Type type = typeof(Store.Proxy);
var value = (Store.Proxy)Store.dmname.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(
                        type.Assembly.FullName,
                        type.FullName);

Assembly = value.GetAssembly(bytes);
```

I tried both ways and I end up at the same thing. Is there a way to load up the assembly to the appdomain using byte[]? I do not want to save It.

Comment: Do you know which side of the AppDomain boundary the exception is occurring on? I notice that you're trying to load an assembly in a "background" AppDomain and return it to the "main" AppDomain. This is going to cause the assembly to be *re-loaded* into the main AppDomain when the return happens. But since you loaded the bytes from memory, I assume the default assembly loading logic will not work for you, hence the error.

Comment: I believe on main. The app downloads an assembly for example, and thats what i want to load on an app domain,

Comment: I think the error is occurring when the assembly is "marshalled" from one AppDomain to the other. When an assembly is "marshalled", I believe it's just re-loaded using standard rules based on assembly name. (That's why I put quotes around "marshalled" -- this object doesn't get marshaled by value or by reference, but through some custom logic.)

Comment: If what I'm saying is true, you should see an `AssemblyResolve` event occur in the main AppDomain. Set up an event handler and see if that event fires in the main AppDomain when the `GetAssembly` call returns in the background AppDomain.

Comment: Uhh, alright will do

Comment: I think I've built something similar to what you're trying to build. If you're trying to examine properties of dynamically-loaded assemblies (or instantiate types of them) without loading the assembly into your main AppDomain, your loader proxy (the one that contains GetAssembly) will need to return a proxy of a different type that has wrapper methods/properties for the methods/properties of `Assembly` (or `Type`) that you're interested in.

Comment: And if you are only performing reflection operations, consider using `Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoad` instead of `Assembly.Load`. By loading for reflection only, it prevents any code in the assembly from actually running.